# How to understand array.foo in this case?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am not sure how to understand this foo property and array here. it looks like foo property got assigned to array, but I don't think it is even valid array syntax. Can someone explain the concept here?

```
var arr = [];
arr[0]  = 'a';
arr[1]  = 'b';
arr.foo = 'c';
console.log(arr) // ['a','b',foo:'c']  This isn't valid array, but Chrome doesn't show any error.
console.log(arr.foo) // 'c'. 
console.log(arr.length); // 2, not 3
```

Comment: Those properties *are* iterable if someone uses a `for in` loop or requests `Object.keys()`.

Comment: You may try declaring `'use strict';` in first line and may get error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaScript arrays *are* objects plus a few methods and some magic involving the `length` property, so yes, you can assign random properties to them.

Don't.

(If you run such an array through JSON, those extra properties will be lost.)

Answer (score 0):

http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch18.html

Here, it is beautifully explained why it has happened, and also some other things, which you might not find common.